# Dynamically overriding an abstract method in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following abstract class which CAN NOT be changed.

```
public abstract class AbstractThing {
   public String GetDescription() {
      return "This is " + GetName();
   }
   public abstract String GetName();
}
```

Now I would like to implement some new dynamic types from this like so.

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
assemblyName.Name = "My.TempAssembly";
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder =  assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicThings");
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(someName + "_Thing", 
                TypeAttributes.Public | 
                TypeAttributes.Class, 
                 typeof(AbstractThing));
MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GetName",    
                MethodAttributes.Public | 
                MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot |
                MethodAttributes.Virtual | 
                MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                null,
                Type.EmptyTypes);

ILGenerator msil = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

msil.EmitWriteLine(selectionList);
msil.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

However when I try to instantiate via

```
typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

I get an exception saying that there is no implementation for GetName. Is there something I am doing wrong here. I can not see the problem.

Also, what would be the restrictions on instantiating such a class by name? For instance if I tried to instantiate via "My.TempAssembly.x_Thing" would it be availble for instantiation without the Type generated?

Comment: What do you mean by "instantiating such a class by name"? Unless you include the generated assembly in your build, you cannot refer to types in it in your program directly. You shall have to use Reflection or `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`.

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what I mean, Type.GetType("My.TempAssembly.x_Thing") then on to Activator.CreateInstance(type). It worked fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the wrong return type on the dynamically created function. It should be `string` instead of `void`:

```
typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GetName",   
MethodAttributes.Public | 
MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot |
MethodAttributes.Virtual | 
MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
typeof(string),
Type.EmptyTypes);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use Func instead. It doesn't require reflection to dynamically change the method.

```
public class AbstractThing {
   public String GetDescription() {
      return "This is " + GetName();
   }
   public Func<String> GetName { get; set; }
}

var thing = new AbstractThing();
thing.GetName = () => "Some Name"; // Or any other method
thing.GetDescription() == "This is Some Name";
```

Comment: This is not really the answer I am looking for, AbstractThing can not be changed. The goal is a string result My.TempAssembly.x_Thing that I can instantiate dynamically.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and it would need to Func, not Action

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question directly, but just another way.